# SharePoint 2016 & SharePoint Online changing Site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, site-template, records-center, document-center

If a site is hosted as a Team site, in either SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2016

Can the template of the site be changed to a Record center or Document Center. If so would the document libraries adapt to it accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

As per experience, it is near to impossible to change the template once you create the site collection. Main reason, MSFT build a structure in each template once you change your existing site collection template then many features not supported in other template and throws the error.

What i would recommend, create a new site collection using the desired template. After this manually move the content from old site to new site.

Comment: Which template do we use for 2016 online ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to change the site template for the existing site.

You will need to provision a new site and then manually copy the data or find a tool that can migrate the content for you. Some of those migration tools can also move permissions as well.